# Why there is exception on grid creation

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-5.0, rowdefinition

I have to create a grid array the size of this array is determined dynamically.

My try to do this is:

```
int size = 4; //This "size" will be determined dynamically.suppose i got 4 here
Grid[] rowgrid = new Grid[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    rowgrid[i].RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
}
```

It don't give any error but when i run it gives exception :
`The object reference is not set to an instance of an object.`

EDIT:
I want to use array because : after intializing before i have to do like this :

```
rowgrid[0].Opacity=0.1;
rowgrid[1].Opacity=0.3;
rowgrid[2].Opacity=0.5;
```

**If you suggest me not work programatically then i want to inform in avance that i know that well but i am obliged to do this because i am working in already developed project and no more options are there.** It would be a big help if some one bring me to come out of this error or any other alternative to achieve this.

Comment: You can use UniformGrid in WPF and bind the property Columns

Comment: @user3735822: You have been told that programmatically manipulating grids to have layout that can deal with dynamic content is **not** the way to do this in Silverlight. You refuse to consider using `ItemControls` and `ImplicitDataTemplates`, fine, but I won't answer any of your "fix my code for me!-"questions.

Comment: In your debugger, which object is giving the null reference? Simple debugging will tell you and should have been your first debugging option. At a guess, from the few lines you've shown I'd say you're trying to add to `RowDefinitions` and that is `null`.

Comment: @Mashton yes your guess is correct. so what should i do it avoid it ?

Comment: Um, instantiate it :/

Comment: @Mashton oK. So it is possible to create a grid array ? you mean to so that ?

Comment: Try this http://bit.ly/1mRAWnf

Answer (score 0):

If you want a Grid with differents Rows or Columns. You can use UniformGrid, columns and rows properties are binding.

So,

```
<UniformGrid Name="uniformGrid1" Rows="{Binding NumberOfRows}" Columns="{Binding NumberOfColumns}">
    <Button Content="Button1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
    <Button Content="Button2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" />
</UniformGrid>
```

In your code

```
private int _numberOfRows;
public int NumberOfRows
    {
        get { return _numberOfRows; }
        set { _numberOfRows= value; RaisePropertyChanged("NumberOfRows"); }
    }    
private int _numberOfColumns;
public int NumberOfColumns
    {
        get { return _numberOfColumns; }
        set { _numberOfColumns= value; RaisePropertyChanged("NumberOfColumns"); }
    } 


public MainViewModel()
{
    NumberOfColumns = 3;
    NumberOfRows = 2;
}
```

Comment: @CampusDev thanks for the answer but i already have knowledge about this. But i am obliged to do it programatically in c# (silverlight) could you please help me indoing so.

Comment: Why are you obliged? Who set such a restrictive limitation? It is like using an OO language and only be able to use primitive types. Sure it's possible, but does beg the question of why you'd want to put yourself through that when using the right tools will make your life so much easier (and the code better).

Comment: But you need manage Grid from Code, Are you will break MVVM model? Because you will be write code behind.